# Forever Frame comet technique?

Tags: real-time, comet

Can someone please explain me how the "Forever Frame" technique works ? A code example would be awesome! I went through all the material i could find in Google but i still don`t have much of an idea how it works.

Answer (score 3):

Dylan Schiemann gives a great explanation.

In short, it uses "chunked encoding", a feature of HTTP/1.1 intended for an entirely different purpose, but which allows the server to maintain a connection to the client indefinitely, sending additional data to the client at will.

As Dylan says :

> This technique is very low-latency because it avoids HTTP and TCP/IP set-up and tear-down by reusing a single long-lived connection.

http://cometdaily.com/2007/11/05/the-forever-frame-technique/

The rest of his article is well worth a read.