# Flickering Issue while binding data to Knockout View

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am developing an `chat application with KO`. While `binding` the chat conversation, the browser is hanging till binding and the `favicon, browser Refresh` and cursor buttons are `blinking` for every message binding.

I've tried like making `visible false by default` and making `visible after binding`. But it didn't worked for me.

Here is the KO code for binding the messages

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(data, function (item) {
                    var msgobj = new ViewMessagesObject();
                    msgobj.Chattype(item.Chattype);
                    msgobj.contactname(item.contactname);
                    msgobj.contactnum(item.contactnum);
                    msgobj.contactpic(item.contactpic);
                    msgobj.deliverydate(item.deliverydate);
                    msgobj.file(item.file);
                    msgobj.frompic(item.frompic);
                    msgobj.is_delivered(item.is_delivered);
                    msgobj.is_read(item.is_read);
                    msgobj.loader(item.loader);
                    msgobj.message(item.message);
                    msgobj.messageid(item.messageid);
                    msgobj.messgetype(item.messgetype);
                    msgobj.Pic(item.Pic);
                    msgobj.readdate(item.readdate);
                    msgobj.sentdate(item.sentdate);
                    msgobj.sentstatus(item.sentstatus);
                    msgobj.toname(item.toname);
                    msgobj.topic(item.topic);
                    msgobj.uploadopacity(item.uploadopacity);

                    self.DisplayMessageCollection.push(msgobj);
}
```

How can I `stop` these flickering issue while binding.

I've attached a `video` that shows the flicker of favicon and refresh button, so that you can understand my problem clearly.

Thanks in Advance..

[Video Demonstrating My Problem](http://owner.uandmestaging.com:88/images/KnockOutFlickeringIssue.swf)

Comment: Does every message property need to be an observable?  I.e. if the message does not change, you can just `self.DisplayMessageCollection.push(item);`

Comment: we've already tried that, but that doesn't work :(

Comment: we've tried direct push for every item, pushAll at once. but nothing's working except this :(

Comment: can you try pushing initially everything into js array later call `valueHasMuated` on it like my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709374/knockout-js-incredibly-slow-under-semi-large-datasets/27252722#27252722 . cheers

Comment: thanks sunil..will try this and let you know :)

Comment: Hello Sunil, we've tried this. but even then the issue still occurs.
actually the flickering issue lies with the binding data to UI, but not the data pushing to array.

Comment: yes flickering happens when binding to UI correct ! . but if you do the above way flickering wont come on each push as you are applying valueHasMuated at the end . i am unable to see the video link (access issue) once i come to see it i can see what exactly going on ..

Comment: Hello Sunil, Actually if you can see the video you will understand it clearly.
Actually everytime we need to clear the whole array and bind new data to that array.
we are not appending some new content to the old array.
I think your solution works in the second case.
please check the video when ever possible and try to find the solution :)

Comment: oops i see it now i never seen one todate. flickering issue is definitely nothing to do with ko binding . for testing please remove fancy css class you using and try the same on plane html it should work without flickering .

Answer (score 1):

The video you have posted shows the *reload* button next to the address bar in chrome spinning and the *favicon* flickering.

The symptoms you describe happen when changing `window.location` in some way.

This happens when:

- navigating to a url
- an `iframe` is injected into the `DOM`
- the `src` attribute of an `iframe` changes
- certain properties on `window.location` object change

This is by no means an exhaustive list of what can cause the *refresh* button to spin in the *chrome* browser **but the code in your answer is not the cause; this is not a knockout related issue at all.**

**Some possible causes to this *issue*:**

- You have some code not posted in your original question that does stuff with `iframes`. Is your chat application possibly using the [forever frame technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985642/forever-frame-comet-technique)?
- You have a chrome plugin that uses `iframes`

I hope this points you in the right direction to solve the issue.